# ember js get meta informations from json

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

i have a json data from my server:

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Progressive Enhancement is Dead",
    "comments": ["1", "2"],
    "links": {
      "user": "/people/tomdale"
    }
  },

  "meta": {
    "total": 100
  }
}
```

look exactly like the documentation (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/handling-metadata/) i try to get the meta object with no success

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    var data = this.store.findAll('post');
    data.then((result) => {
      let meta = result.get('meta');
      console.log(meta); //this return me undefined
    })
    return data;
  }
});
```

Comment: What version of Ember do you use?

Comment: the last version 2.5.1

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3419
It looks that this is not possible for one record meta, it looks to me that you have only one post, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: no i only removed some record for the example and it's discussion about litlle different problem i get my exemple directly from the documentation so you think it's a ember bug or its from my code ?

Comment: I'm not sure, your code looks good but I doubt that this is Ember bug. The only difference that I see is that in documentation they use store.query() and you're using findAll.

Comment: thanks to you for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using findAll method and it does not support meta data. You should use `this.store.query('post', {/*params*/})` method instead, if you want to get multiple posts with meta data.

Comment: ok thanks you're right but i dont understand why i can't use the findAll method (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/finding-records/) it's little ambigous for me

Comment: I guess the reason is, that ember expects to have EVERYTHING returned from an API when doing a findAll, so expects no need for any meta data. But this is just a guess, that would explain such behaviour to me.