# Ember: Not getting meta information in FindAll response

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember **2.5.1**

I am trying to fetch all comments using rest service with **store.findAll('comment')** and got response for the same. I have a meta information in the response which gives the count of total comments. But I am not getting those information in route as it is giving record array for comments only.

**Response**

```
{
 "comments": [{
    "id": 167,
    "entityId": 120,
    "userId": 41,
    "editedBy": 41,
    "text": "Sample comments"
  }, {
    "id": 171,
    "entityId": 120,
    "userId": 41,
    "editedBy": null,
    "text": "comment text"
  }],
 "meta": {
    "sumOfComments": 5
 }
}
```

I tried **extractMeta** in my custom serializer, but it is giving no records after adding this.

```
extractMeta: function(store, type, payload) {
  if (payload && payload.meta.sumOfComments) {
    store.setMetadataFor(type, { sumOfComments: payload.meta.sumOfComments }); 
  }
}
```

Can any one suggest a solution to get those meta information in routes.

Comment: Did you check for solution here
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/handling-metadata/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
store.findAll('comment').then((result) => {
  let meta = result.get('meta');
})
```

Comment: I tried the same, but it is giving 'undefined'.

Comment: You have an answer to your question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645345/ember-js-get-meta-informations-from-json

Comment: Thank you Jovica.. I am getting the meta info after changing the store.findAll to store.query.